# Performance impact of using css / javascript source-maps in production?

Tags: javascript, css, httprequest, production-environment, source-maps

- Should source-maps be used in production environment? Do they provide any benefits other than debugging?
- Do they impact app load time due to the additional server round-trips? Are browsers smart enough to load `.map` assets after app is loaded and rendered?
- If a browser cannot find the `.map` asset (`404` error), would there be performance impact? Should I care about fixing it?

Note that fixing the last one may not be as easy as serving the `.map` assets if there are complicated concat / minify build steps.

Comment: Well, a pointless HTTP request definitely takes time and bandwidth.

Comment: Did I miss something? Isn't source-maps meant for debugging, wouldn't you eventually remove those in production code ?

Comment: Because source maps are located in comments, I would assume that the browser ignores them until they are specifically requested, such as in the developer console.

Comment: @Wex sourcemaps can be inlined or served as separate `.map` file; @others, perhaps I'm asking this just for clarification that there are no benefits other than debugging. However since so many js libraries are expecting `.map`, such as `AngularJS`, did we just place undue burden on the web by inventing sourcemaps?

Comment: @Wex This is what I thought as well but it would be nice to have a definitive answer. Are external .map assets requested only when the developer opens the developer tools? What about inline source maps?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

A quick test using [Charles Web Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) shows that source maps are **only** loaded if developer tools are opened.  If you load a page **without** dev tools opened, there is no http request for source maps.

The behaviour was the same in Chrome 43 and Firefox 38.

So it appears they would be no impact on production environment.

Answer (score -1):

From HTML5 Rocks:

> Basically it's a way to map a combined/minified file back to an
>   unbuilt state. When you build for production, along with minifying and
>   combining your JavaScript files, you generate a source map which holds
>   information about your original files. When you query a certain line
>   and column number in your generated JavaScript you can do a lookup in
>   the source map which returns the original location. Developer tools
>   (currently WebKit nightly builds, Google Chrome, or Firefox 23+) can
>   parse the source map automatically and make it appear as though you're
>   running unminified and uncombined files.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all, it's just explaining what a sourcemap is.