# Is it okay to delete *.min.js.map while minifying the js files?

Tags: angularjs, minify, bundling-and-minification, map-files, minifiedjs

I am using WEB ESSENTILS extension of Visual Studio for minification of JS files. After minifying the js file I am getting a `.map` extension file linked with the minified version of that js file. So the size of `.min.js + .map > .js` file. So I am thinking to remove all the `.map` files to reduce the size.
I am worried if it causes any problem in production. Please suggest!

**My Analysis :**
I have went through lot of stuff on web and got to know that `.map` file will only be used for debugging minified files. But I saw people posting questions like :

- `.map` not found error (404)
- and many more.

So need your suggestion on this.

Comment: If you care about being able to debug production code easier, then keep it. Otherwise you can safely delete them.

Comment: @Vlada yes I don't want to debug it. So I can simply right click and delete right?

Comment: There is a good read about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848364/performance-impact-of-using-css-javascript-source-maps-in-production