# Generate production build with sourcemaps in Angular - CLI

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular-cli

How to keep sourcemaps after production build?

Right now, my command looks like this:

`"build-prod": "ng build --app=release -prod && cp -R lang dist"`

I tried changing it to:

`ng build --app=release --sourceMap=true -prod && cp -R lang dist`

but nothing changed.

If I do:
`ng build --sourcemap` I get sourcemaps but then I get index.html instead of index.prod.html.

Is it possible to edit the first command to build sourcemap files?

this is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```js
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2017",
            "dom"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 33):

You should edit your `angular.json` like this

```
"configurations": {
    "production": {
        "fileReplacements": [
            {
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
        ],
        "optimization": true,
        "outputHashing": "all",
        "sourceMap": false, // change to true
```

Then run

```
ng build --prod
```

But I wouldnt recommend you turn on source map in production because it will increase a bundle size

Comment: I have "sourceMap": true in my tsconfig file, shouldn't that be enough? I only have tsconfig.json and angular-cli.json or is angular-cli.json same as angular.json?

Comment: that tsconfig only support for dev mode. You need to set in angular.json for prod. angular-cli. json is out of date version.  Lastest angular cli used angular. json

Comment: Note that source maps generally only get downloaded if the users opens their developer tools, so for most users having the source maps available *won't* impact download size: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23848364/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe They are helpful if you have an enterprise setup where you have multiple lower states before production. Then you can test and debug in a prod like environment. You can then turn it off for real prod. Or have a third config for prod-test.

Comment: For Angular V14.2 I had to write "ng build --configuration production" to consider production configuration with enabled source maps.

Answer (score 16):

you can try

```
ng build --prod --source-map=true|false
```

[angular.io/cli/build](https://angular.io/cli/build)