# No component factory found for t. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Tags: angular, angular6, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

I have created a component to preview docx and pdf files natively in my project(angular 6).To preview pdf, I have used [ng2-pdf-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer) and to preview docx, docx file is converted to html in the backend and send to angular. Preview for docx and pdf is working fine on local machine, but does not work on the server.
The error in the console is shown below. In the error it mentions component 't'. I don't think there such component. It might be another bug.

[image]

html file:

```
<loading-spinner *ngIf="loading"></loading-spinner>
<div *ngIf="!loading">
<!-- for pdf  -->
<pdf-viewer *ngIf="isPdf" [src]="pdfSrc" style="display: block;" (after-load-complete)="afterLoading()"
 (error)="onError()" (contextmenu)="onRightClick()" [zoom]="zoom">
</pdf-viewer>
<!-- for docx  -->
<div class="container" *ngIf="isDocx">
 <div [innerHTML]="html" class="doc" (contextmenu)="onRightClick()" (click)="onLeftClick()"></div>
</div>

</div>


<button class="btn btn-light zoomIn" (click)="zoomIn()"><i class="fa fa-search-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
<button class="btn btn-light zoomOut" (click)="zoomOut()"><i class="fa fa-search-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { PublicService } from '../public.service';
declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-file-preview',
  templateUrl: './file-preview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./file-preview.component.css']
})

@Directive({ selector: '[preventCutCopyPaste]' })

export class FilePreviewComponent implements OnInit {

  fileName;
  siteUrl = environment.resourcecUrl + "/";
  doc;
  loading = true;
  isPdf = false;
  isDocx = false;
  html;
  pdfSrc;
  zoom = 1;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    public publicService: PublicService,
    el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer2
  ) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.fileName = params['fileName'];
      this.pdfSrc = this.siteUrl + "upload/project/" + this.fileName;
      this.checkFileType();
    });
    //disable copy
    var events = 'cut copy paste';
    events.split(' ').forEach(e =>
      renderer.listen(el.nativeElement, e, (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
      })
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  zoomIn() {
    this.zoom += 0.1;
    console.log(this.zoom);
  }
  zoomOut() {
    this.zoom -= 0.1;
    console.log(this.zoom);
  }


  checkFileType() {
    const res = this.fileName.split('.');
    const fileType = res[res.length - 1];
    if (fileType == 'pdf') {
      this.isPdf = true;
    } else if (fileType == 'docx') {
      this.isDocx = true;
      this.publicService.docx2html(this.fileName).subscribe(
        response => {
          this.html = response;
          // console.log(response);
          this.loading = false;
        })
    } else {
      this.onError();
    }
  }

  onRightClick() {
    return false;
  }
  onLeftClick() {
    return false;
  }

  afterLoading() {
    this.loading = false;
  }

  onError() {
    alert("Cannot load file");
  }

}
```

Comment: That's most likely the minified variable name. Try running locally in prod mode with source maps enabled to find what is getting borked.

Comment: I would suggest upgrading to Angular 9+, you will not need to have to add components in the entryComponents array

Comment: @Phix can you tell me how to run locally in prod mode with source maps .

Comment: @OwenKelvin upgrading to angular 9 can break my project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57660537/generate-production-build-with-sourcemaps-in-angular-cli

Comment: @Phix I got an error when building with source maps